# Receive RTP (Pipeline demo)

Tags: gstreamer, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-deepstream

setup:

• Hardware Platform:Jetson Xavier NX

• DeepStream Version: 6.1

• JetPack Version: 5.0.1 DP

• TensorRT Version: 8.4.0.11

• Issue Type( questions)

Hi folks,
I work with deepstream and python bindings I have pipeline that captare UDP H264 stream pass to Yolo object detection and tracking, everything work great.
Now I need to handle with something new so before I integrate my network I try build simple pipeline in command line.
someone Send to me RTP stream is pipeline (Sender):

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device="/dev/video” ! jpegdec ! omxh264enc ! mpegtsmux ! rtpmp2tpay ! udpsink host=234.0.0.0 port=46002
```

I build a simple receive pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=46002 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)MP2T, payload=(int)33" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpmp2tdepay ! tsdemux ! h264parse ! nvv4l2decoder ! nvvideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

Unfortntaly I don’t see video on screen I thing something worng with the element rtpmp2tdepay or maybe I missing out something I will be happy to any help.
I add some graphsView of the pipeline and wireshark:
[image]

[image]

I thing I miss something I would happy to any help.